# How can i read large EmailMessage object using wb+ if the file is large using python3?

Tags: python, email

I wish to write a very large EmailMessage object using binary in small sizes just like it is done using buffer.read(1024). IS there a way?
I have tried like this  which is wrong as the Email Message object is not having read() method:

```
    with open(complete_path,'wb+') as fp:
        while True:
            x = msg.read(1024)
            if x:
                fp.write(x.as_bytes())
            else:
                break
        fp.write(x.as_bytes())
```

Here **msg** is the EmailMessage object and trying to save it at location **complete_path** When tried with below code it works for most of the mails but does not complete and gets stuck for few mails and generated zombies:

```
      with open(complete_path,'wb+') as fp:
          fp.write(msg.as_bytes())
```

I am reading the email in a fuglu plugin and not from a file.
Please guide.

Comment: " it works for most of the mails but does not complete and gets stuck for few mails and generated zombies". I suspect this is more likely to be a problem outside of Python.  The `with` statement will automatically flush the file when it closes it.

Comment: @snakecharmerb the The fp.write() part was put in try:except but it doesn't yield any logs either in try nor in except block